# ClosedXML Webform - foreach loop looping twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

So my problem is when I am trying to read excel file it prints output correct in gridview once, but when I try to store the row[cells] - only into an String variable using serials += row[cells] it is looping through the foreach loop twice, and I can't figure out how to solve it!

**WebForm1.aspx <- contains a form Fileupload button and gridview to uplad and read Excel File**

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    String serials = "";
    int sheetRowCount = 0;
    int rowCount = 0;
    int ColumnCount = 0;
    int i, rownum=0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // checking File Extension
        if (checkFileExtension())
        {

            // reading File if extension is true
            readExcelFile();

        }

    }

    private bool checkFileExtension()
    {
        String[] allowedExtensions = { "xls", "xlsx" };
        String ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        bool isValidFile = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ext == "." + allowedExtensions[i])
            {
                isValidFile = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isValidFile)
        {
            error1.Text = "Allowed FileTypes are .xls/.xlsx";
            return isValidFile;
        }
        else
        {
            readExcelFile();
            return isValidFile;
        }
    }

    private void readExcelFile()
    {
        // to bind data table to gridview
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // creating new workbook object and sending Uploaded File as input File
        using (XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {
            // creating excel worksheet object to access worksheet from workbook(Excel File)
            IXLWorksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);

            // initializing 1st row
            bool firstRow = true;
            foreach (IXLRow row in sheet.Rows())
            {
                sheetRowCount++;
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SHEET ROW COUNT: " + sheetRowCount);
                // printing 1st row as headers of Table DATA
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    // getting cells of 1st row
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        // adding full 1st row cells into data table
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    // making 1st row = false as 1st is finished
                    firstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    rowCount++;
                    rownum++;
                  
                    // as it is 2nd row it will be printed as normal text
                    // adding empty rows in sheet
                    dt.Rows.Add();

                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rows Count : " + rowCount);
                    // variable for couting row
                    i = 0;
                    // getting cells in rows
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        // to stop Row indexer we use row count - 1 as it loops
                        // it always keep row to row - 1 to add value to corrent row
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        ColumnCount++;
                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Column Count: " + ColumnCount);
                        i++;
                    }

                }
                

            }
        }

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("=====================================");
        // sheet Row Count
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SHEET ROW COUNT: " + sheetRowCount);
        sheetRowCount = 0;
        // Row Count
        ///System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rows Count : " + rowCount);
        rowCount = 0;

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Current Row: " + rownum);
        rownum = 0;

        //Column Count
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Current Column: " + i);
        i = 0;

        //DATA TABLE
        // setting data source to gridview
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        // binding data to gridview
        GridView1.DataBind();


        gettingAllSerialsIntoArrayToJSON(dt);
    }

    private void gettingAllSerialsIntoArrayToJSON(DataTable dt)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("after printing: " + dt.Rows.Count);
        // For each row, print the values of each column.
        // 2 rows  - ROW 0 -- Row 1
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // 1 column
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                serials += i + "-" + j + " : " + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "END LINE   ";
            }
        }

        error1.Text = serials;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of the content of serials to show us the duplication? Also, is it the i loop or the j loop that you think is running twice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out! I was calling readExcel() function twice my boolean function which returned true as file is xls/xlsx there I was calling readExcel() which made duplication of values example

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // checking File Extension
    if (checkFileExtension())
    {

        // reading File if extension is true
        readExcelFile();  ===> here after checking extension I have to use function

    }

}

private bool checkFileExtension()
{
    String[] allowedExtensions = { "xls", "xlsx" };
    String ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    bool isValidFile = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ext == "." + allowedExtensions[i])
        {
            isValidFile = true;
        }
    }

    if (!isValidFile)
    {
        error1.Text = "Allowed FileTypes are .xls/.xlsx";
        return isValidFile;
    }
    else
    {
        readExcelFile();  <== this is wrong as this function is only used to return file extension validation
        return isValidFile;
    }
}
```

thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: I am not able to Tick or edit my question to add TAG [SOLVED] as I cannot check my own answer, can you answer so I can check and make it as solved

Comment: You can mark your reply as an answer by clicking "✔" without adding the [Resolved] tag. This also tells others that your problem is solved.

Comment: What do you mean, you cannot [edit] your own post? That should be possible. Are you logged in?